# Separate parameters from single array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is my single length array

```
array(1) { ["http://abc_cde_com/riseres_php?TransactionID=2517055&Amount=1_00&AuthorizationCode=MB0118&ResultID=0&ResultMessage=APPROVED_OR_COMPLETED_SUCCESSFULLY_&ResponseCode=00&ResponseMessage=OPERATION_IS_APPROVED_(SIM)&HostResponseMsg=OPERATION_IS_APPROVED_(SIM)&ReferenceNumber=XYZ123&3DProvider=___"] => string(0) "" }
```

How do I can get TransactionID and ReferenceNumber from above array and same others as well?

Comment: the array is irrelevant. it's just a url. http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: The parser comment is right; why is the Url in an array? It looks like you need $_GET

Comment: $my=$_GET;
foreach($my as $key => $value)
{

$hello= explode('?', $key);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($hello);

}

Comment: By using $key values i got the values, i do not know it is good practice or not but by explode i got all my required values  thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

By using `parse_url` and `parse_str` to turn the $_GET parameters into an assoc array. Like so (assumes your array is called `$input`)

```
$parsed = parse_url(current($input));
parse_str($parsed['query'], $params);
$transactionID = $params['TransactionID'];
$referenceNumber = $params['ReferenceNumber']
```